# Passing arguments to modules in IPython when using run -m

Tags: python, ipython, argparse

I just installed the git master branch of IPython. The following:

```
In [1]: run -m my_packages.my_module -verbosity 20
```

returns an error:

```
UsageError: option -v not recognized ( allowed: "nidtN:b:pD:l:rs:T:em:G" )
```

Even though the following works:

```
$ python -m my_packages.my_module -verbosity 20
```

I am using `argparse` as follows:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='my_program')
parser.add_argument('-verbosity',   help='Verbosity', required=True)
```

Any thoughts why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `--` to stop the command-line parsing at a certain point:

```
In [1]: %run -m my_packages.my_module -- -verbosity 20
```

This is standard behavior [used by argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing) for adding extra positional arguments.